# slide up and slide down within slide panel

Tags: jquery

Hopefully someone will understand this.
I apologise if my code is crap, I am trying. Anyhoo.
I want to have a slide up slide down panel, which shows comments.
Onclick the comments panel OPENS, and onclick Closes.
But when it opens, a link appears on right hand side, that opens the panel up some more for a form .
It kinda works, but panels arent closing when the proper element is clicked.
Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/Rv3LY/
Basically.
Want it so, user clicks comments to open them.
Then they click Close to close comments OR
They could click Post a comment which slides down the form.
Or Close everything.

Any help appreciated, I suppose its all rather straightforward, just going round in circles lol. Apologies if my code is crap.

Comment: Does every sentence you write really need a paragraph break?

Comment: Thats iPads for you edited to keep you Happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:http://jsfiddle.net/Rv3LY/1/